# If y=y(x) and $\frac{2+sin(x)}{y+1}\frac{dy}{dx}=-cosx,y(0)=1$, then find $y(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

If y=y(x) and $\frac{2+sin(x)}{y+1}\frac{dy}{dx}=-cosx,y(0)=1$, then find $y(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

---

**My attempt:-**
$$\frac{2+sin(x)}{y+1}\frac{dy}{dx}=-cosx$$
$$\frac{dy}{1+y}=-\frac{cos(x)}{2+sin(x)}dx$$
Integrating both sides
$$\int\frac{dy}{1+y}=-\int\frac{cos(x)}{2+sin(x)}dx$$
$$log(1+y)=-log(2+sin(x))+C$$
$$log(1+y)=log(\frac{1}{2+sin(x)})+C$$
Antilog on both sides
$$1+y=\frac{1}{2+sin(x)}+C$$
$$y=\frac{-1-sin(x)}{2+sin(x)}+C$$
Now it is given that $y(0)=1$
So $$y(0)=1=\frac{-1-sin(0)}{2+sin(0)}+C$$
$$1=\frac{-1}{2}+C$$
$$C=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$y(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{-1-sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}{2+sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}+C$$
$$y(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{-2}{3}+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$y(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{5}{6}$$

But the answer happens to be $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: When you take the antilog, the additive $C$ should turn into a multiplicative factor of $A = e^C$ (recall that $\exp (a + b) = \exp(a) \cdot \exp(b)$.

Comment: In order to be brief, integrate right away over $x\ \in\ \left(\, 0,{\pi \over 2}\, \right)$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 spotted where you went wrong. To solve the exercise, prove that the function $$(2+\sin x)\cdot(1+y(x))$$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake by antiloging. The line $ 1+y=\frac{1}{2+\sin(x)}+C $ is wrong.

It would be easier if you would write $\log C$ instead $C$ in the line before. So in the next step you would get:
$$1+y=\frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} \cdot C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{2+\sin(x)}{y+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\cos(x)
$$
Separating variables gives
$$
\int\frac1{y+1}\mathrm{d}y=-\int\frac{\cos(x)}{2+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Integrating yields
$$
\log(y+1)=C_1-\log(2+\sin(x))
$$
or
$$
y=\frac{C}{2+\sin(x)}-1
$$
Since $y(0)=1$, we get $C=4$. Thus, $y\,\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac13$.

Comment: There are two answers for $y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, it is $\frac{1}{3}$ but also $-\frac{7}{3}$.

Comment: I would say that your second solution is wrong, Jan.

Comment: @Icarus369 Well, you might say that! But explain me why? Because you said in your answer for example that $\int-\frac{y'(x)}{1+y(x)}\space\text{d}x=\text{C}-\ln(1+y(x))$ and I think that is wrong. Because the absolute value sign is there for a reason.

Comment: I can explain my logic. Let's begin from this step: $-\ln|1+y(x)|=\ln|2+\sin(x)|+{C_1} $. If we write $\ln |C_1|$ instead of $C_1$ we will get $|1+y(x)| = \big| \frac{C_1}{2 + \sin x} \big|$. That means that $y(x) = \pm \frac{C_1}{2 + \sin x} - 1 = \frac{C}{2 + \sin x} - 1$ (the expression from my answer - because of that I wrote it without the apsolut value). Using the initial condition, we can find that the only solution is $ y(x) = \frac{2 - \sin x}{2 + \sin x} $, so we get $\frac{1}{3}$ as the only answer.

Comment: Also, from the step $ |1+y(x)| = \big| \frac{C_1}{2 + \sin x} \big| $ we have either $  1 + y(x) =  \frac{C_1}{2 + \sin x} $ or $  1 + y(x) =  - \frac{C_1}{2 + \sin x} $. If we use the first expresion, we get $C_1 =  4 $, and $C_1 = - 4$ from the second. That leads to the same function $y(x) = \frac{2 - \sin x}{2 + \sin x}$, so the supstitution of $ \pm C_1 $ to $C$ makes sense. What is the function $y(x)$ witch has the value $ - \frac{7}{3}$ in $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$, and is the solution of this equation?

Comment: The absolute value sign is usually there so that when $\log|x|+C$ is exponentiated, we can get $\pm e^Cx$. I think a better way to write the integral is $\log(Cx)$, then the constant can be negative. We still have to be careful as $x$ passes through $0$. This usually means handling $x\gt0$ and $x\lt0$ separately. Otherwise, writing $\log|x|+C$ allows wildly discontinuous solutions.

Comment: @Icarus369: indeed, $\frac13$ is the only solution. This is also shown in my comment to Jan Eerland's answer.